# S3Client::GetObject with SetRange returns wrong data?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to read a segment of a large AWS S3 Object starting with the first 1048576 bytes.  I specify the range of bytes that I want to read but I do not receive those bytes.  The length returned is correct.

I am fairly new at this so I'm probably doing something wrong and being a C programmer instead of C++ has not helped a lot.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
int   start=0, rbytes=0;

Aws::S3::S3Client  s3_client;
Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest read_object_request;
sprintf(range,"bytes=%lld-%lld",start,start+1048575);

read_object_request.SetBucket(container_name);
read_object_request.SetKey(object_name);
read_object_request.SetRange(range);
auto results = s3_client.GetObject(read_object_request);
if (results.IsSuccess())
{
   rbytes = results.GetResult().GetContentLength();
   std::cout << rbytes << " bytes read" << std::endl;
}
memcpy(bdata,results.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf(),rbytes);
```

I then dump the bdata buffer and it is not what I expected.  When I repeat the execution of the code, a new instance, it returns different data.

Though I don't show it the   bdata  buffer is pre-allocated 2 megabytes.

Any ideas that would point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try and determine if it's a problem with your C++ code by running the equivalent ranged get using the awscli (aws s3api get-object --range="bytes=1-20" ...). I would run both this and your code against the first 20 bytes of a known text file for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I really should have done that before I posted.  I used the aws cli and it did indeed download the requested range.

Comment: I think you need to stream from the read buffer into a string or byte array. For example (if it's a text file): Aws::StringStream ss; ss << xyz.rdbuf(), then look at ss.str().c_str().

Answer (score 1):

`rdbuf()` is a stream and you are treating it as a memory pointer.

Comment: You are correct, thanks.  Your response sent me on a different search and to a working result.  Much appreciated.  I needed the output in a buffer I controlled so I did the following: 
streambuf* body = results.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf();  body->sgetn(buffer,rbytes);

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final code for anyone who's interested.  I would also appreciate any comments you see fit to make.

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/HeadObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/HeadObjectResult.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/Object.h>

long scanObject(Aws::String region,
                Aws::String bucket_name,
                Aws::String object_name);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   long scanned=0;

   if (argc < 4){ return(1); }
   Aws::String region = argv[1];
   Aws::String bucket_name = argv[2];
   Aws::String object_name = argv[3];

   Aws::SDKOptions options;
   Aws::InitAPI(options);

   scanned = scanObject(region,bucket_name,object_name);
   printf("Scanned %d bytes of object\n",scanned);

   Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

   return(0);
}

long scanObject(Aws::String region,
                Aws::String bucket_name,
                Aws::String object_name)
{
   int   rbytes, nbytes;
   char range[48], *buffer;
   long filesize, bytesleft, start;

   Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration cconfig;
   cconfig.region = region;
   Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(cconfig);

   Aws::S3::Model::HeadObjectRequest head_object_request;
   head_object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(object_name);
   Aws::S3::Model::HeadObjectOutcome head_object;
   head_object = s3_client.HeadObject(head_object_request);
   if (!head_object.IsSuccess())
   {
      printf("AWS Object, /%s/%s, failed to locate\n",
             region.c_str(),object_name.c_str());
      return(-1);
   }

   filesize = head_object.GetResult().GetContentLength();
   bytesleft = filesize;

   start = 0;
   nbytes = 1048576;
   buffer = (char*)malloc(nbytes*2);

   Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest read_request;
   while(bytesleft > 0)
   {
      if (bytesleft > 1048576){ nbytes = 1048576; }else{ nbytes = bytesleft; }

      sprintf(range,"bytes=%d-%d",start,start+nbytes-1);

      read_request.SetBucket(bucket_name);
      read_request.SetKey(object_name);
      read_request.SetRange(range);

      auto results = s3_client.GetObject(read_request);

      if (!results.IsSuccess())
      {
         printf("\nUnable to fetch object range %s from s3 bucket.\n",range);
         return(-1);
      }
      rbytes = results.GetResult().GetContentLength();

      std::streambuf* body = results.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf();
      body->sgetn(buffer,rbytes);

      start += rbytes;
      bytesleft -= rbytes;
   }

   return(filesize);
}
```

I'm sure this could be done in a more efficient manner and hopefully I will learn that as I go along.